# Postgres Database not being Created by Docker-Compose.yml file

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile

**This error is ONLY occurring on one of my 4 devices, and I am trying to debug it.** This device is a Macbook pro with an Intel processor.
The database container (db service) spins up but doesn't create the database.

```
version: "3.7" 
services:   
  db:
    networks:
      new:
          aliases:
              - database
    restart: always
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_DB=core
      # - PGDATA=/tmp
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  migrate:
    image: migrate/migrate
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
        - new
    volumes:
        - ./db/migrations:/migrations
    command: ["-path", "/migrations", "-database",  "postgres://user:password@database:5432/core?sslmode=disable", "up"]
    links: 
        - db
  web:
    networks:
      - new
    build: . 
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/server
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      PORT: 8080
      CONNECTION_STRING_DEV: db://user:password@db:5433/db
      DSN: "db://user:password@db:5433/core"
  redis:
    networks:
      - new
    image: "redis"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
networks:
  new:
```

The container stops at `2022-01-19 15:37:02.916 UTC [49] LOG: database system is ready to accept connections` and never actually executes "CREATE DATABASE"

Because the database isn't created, my connected Go API isn't functioning properly. The docker-compose should be creating the database "core", spinning up the redis instance, and then spinning up the web service. Afterwards, I typically pull up the migrate container which makes my database migrations. All of my other devices (macOS, windows, and linux), function properly and bring up the database when `docker-compose up web` is run.

Answer (score 0):

here is warning from postgresql docker image page:

```
Warning: scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d are only run if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup. One common problem is that if one of your /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d scripts fails (which will cause the entrypoint script to exit) and your orchestrator restarts the container with the already initialized data directory, it will not continue on with your scripts.
```

so one of the reason that your host you are using has something in `./pgdata`

also you they have pretty detailed documentation on how you can extend image or run something on startup - you can actually clean up everything on first  startup.

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres